# Adding CUDA to EXISTING VSS 2013 DLL project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, cuda

I have an existing Win32 DLL that compiles in VSS 2013.

I also have the correct CUDA tools installed, as I am successfully able to create a new CUDA 7.0 runtime project within VCC.

However, i am unable to figure out how to integrate the CUDA into my existing project so that I may add CUDA functions to my existing source.

Answer (score 1):

To have CUDA working you would need to:

- Have `nvcc` compile your `.cu` files - I think this happens as soon as the CUDA build rules are enabled in the project (but I can be wrong) because VS automatically uses them for all `.cu` files. This step gives you `.o` produced from your `.cu` files by `nvcc`.
- Link against the needed CUDA libraries ('cudart` and friends) to resolve the driver and CUDA API calls in your code - this can be achieved by adding the needed CUDA libraries as linker inputs under the VS linker property page.

[These](http://www.cs.utah.edu/~mhall/cs4961f10/CUDA-VS08.pdf) instructions should cover enabling the CUDA build rules and adding the needed libraries as linker inputs.

Comment: Okay, i have successfully added a .CU to the project, and it seems to be using the Cuda C compiler. But, with an empty .CU file, im getting some weird errors..

Error 3 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___cudaRegisterFatBinary@4 referenced in function "void __cdecl __nv_cudaEntityRegisterCallback(void * *)" (?__nv_cudaEntityRegisterCallback@@YAXPAPAX@Z) C:\PROJECTS\PVlib\CudaPV.cu.obj PVlib

Comment: I believe the answer given is correct.  You started out asking a very general question, now you are faced with a very specific problem. It might be time to pose a new question, with the specifics and an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @iBoston which CUDA libraries did you add as the linker input?